# Spring Boot Application No ServletContext set when starting Jar File

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a very basic Spring application without any database connection. When i run the application main class from intellij it works. However, when I build it and execute the jar from command line I get below error message.

You can see part of my application below.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class GmpDevAutomationBeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GmpDevAutomationBeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class JGitController {

    @GetMapping("/branches")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getBranches(@RequestParam String userName, @RequestParam String password) {

        JGitService jGitService = new JGitService(userName,password);
        return jGitService.getBranches();

    }


}
```

I am using the following maven plugin to build my jar.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>net.regnology.devautomation.GmpDevAutomationBeApplication</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

```
17:12:11.895 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
17:12:11.898 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
        ...
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at net.regnology.devautomation.GmpDevAutomationBeApplication.main(GmpDevAutomationBeApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Do not use maven-assembly-plugin... use the spring-boot-maven-plugin which is intended for that purpose... with maven-assembly-plugin you will not achieve that... (easy)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `maven-assembly-plugin` you can try using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>net.regnology.devautomation.GmpDevAutomationBeApplication</mainClass>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you have the `spring-boot-starter-parent` in you pom, you do not have to define `repackage` as a goal. You can then just call `mvn package` and the jar should run.